# Skrollr-Menu not initializing

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I'm trying to use skrollr on mobile, it works but it's breaking my anchor links

I've tried using skrollr-menu. However, when I do

```
skrollr.menu.init(s);
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Please help!

**More info**

I'm doing this on an app that's using rails. It also uses foundation 5.

Comment: Make sure the required js file(s) are included before you make that call.

Comment: ^ agreed also make sure your JS files are structured properly to deal with all dependencies..